# how to search gzcompress string with PHP regex correct?

Tags: php

I have a file where the string is encoded from the gzcompress function, Here's my code snippet.

```
---snipp---;eval($���('x�����/�(PP���V�b���NNu...'));---snipp--
```

I used regex to get the string, and it worked This is my code

```
$file=utf8_encode(file_get_contents('file.php'));
if(preg_match('/(?:;eval\(\$[\x{0080}-\x{FFFF}]*?\(\'(.*?)\'\)\);)/us',$file,$match)){
    $gsString = $match[1][0]; // This is the gzstring I want to get 
    $decodeString = gzuncompress(utf8_decode($gzString));
    echo $decodeString;
}
```

When I try to use gzuncompress it always shows an error like the following.

```
Warning: gzuncompress(): data error in ..//here path file..
```

so why gzcompress string becomes curropt when i get it using regex?
Or is there a way to get only the gzcompress string?

Comment: Compressed data is binary. What sense does it make to apply `utf8_decode()` on it?

Comment: because previously I encoded the $file variable to utf-8, so I thought to restore it as before., do you have a way to decode the compressed data?

Comment: If needed, you need to re-encode the uncompressed data, not the (binary) compressed data.

Comment: can you give me a reference for me to study?

Comment: `utf8_decode(gzuncompress($gzString))`